# Moving site to another domain, install appears

Tags: 7, migrations

I move the website to another domain on the same server, by copying all files to the other domain's folder.
When I visit the new domain the install.php appears. Trying to navigate to another page like /user/login redirects to the installer as well.

I don't think I need to change database settings because it's on the same server.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When install appears on a site that you expect to be fully installed, the problem is usually with the file `settings.php` (in the `sites/default/` directory).

It may be missing in action, not visible to the web server user, or unable to establish the credentials to connect to the site's database.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. sites/default had no write permissions, so my copy failed there.

Answer (score 2):

As Gisle said problem looks with settings.php either it has not been created or your web server has not permissions to read it,check under sites/default directory. If its not there then just copy the default settings.php and change database settings as your current database details.
As a gentle reminder ensure you have .htaccess file in your drupal root directory if your server is linux based , this file will be hidden.